# Multiple chained lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, currying

I stumbled across this [code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121575/remove-character-at-specified-index):

> Given a string `s` and an integer `n` representing an index in `s`, output `s` with the character at the `n`-th position removed.

The highest-voted [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121577) (as of this post) is in C#.

```
s=>n=>s.Remove(n,1);
```

---

What is this multiple `=>` syntax? It looks similar to a lambda expression `(s,n)=>s.Remove(n,1)`, but I can't figure out how to use this code.

Comment: `s=>n=>s.Remove(n,1)` ~ `(s) => ((n) => s.Remove(n,1)));` The function taking `s` returns another function (establishing a closure over `s`) taking `n`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite simple when it's spread out a bit!

```
s =>
     n =>
         s.Remove(n, 1);
```

Let's call our function `fn`: calling `fn` with a variable `s` returns another function which takes a variable `n`.

```
fn("hello")(0)
```

You can see that after calling `fn("hello")`, we are actually given this:

```
n => "hello".Remove(n, 1);
```

So when we call the returned function, we execute that by giving it an `n`.

Comment: Lambda expressions cannot be assigned to `var`.

Comment: Saves 2 bytes over the more standard `(s,n)=>s.Remove(n,1);`

Comment: Right you are @apk, I've updated my answer. Too much JavaScript lately :P

Comment: @itsme86 That explanation helped it "click" for me. Thanks!

Comment: "In mathematics and computer science, **currying** is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument." That's not what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like a valid answer to me without the type definition:

```
Func<string, Func<int, string>> f = s => n => s.Remove(n, 1);

string result = f("123")(1);   // "13"
```

Comment: As an expression bodied function: `Func<string, Func<int, string>> f=>s=>n=>s.Remove(n, 1);`